# Cakephp3.0 model how new orm model work

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0

Hey I am trying to retrieve  data  from a table I am able to get through tableregistry inside controller my controller name is messagecontroller.ph mysql table name is messages :
and here is my code

```
 public function view($pid)
{

    $messages = TableRegistry::get('Messages');
 $query = $messages->find();

 foreach ($query as $row) {
   echo $row->title;
  }
```

how to do this in messagetable I mean how to write it in message table and how to show that in controller or it will directly interact with view

Comment: Before you get too far, you need to visit the CakePHP Book. The approach you are taking is totally wrong... The developers have put a lot of work to get this book together.. I have read the entire book once and I am constantly referring back so I do see the effort they have put it to make sure people are easily introduced to the CakePHP framework... that is your best bet.. Review the BOOK http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html

Comment: I have some problem I just want to understand with example

Comment: Read the manual. It includes code examples and is a structured way to learn about the framework and ORM. Your question shows that you put *zero* effort in reading something and just go by trial and error and ask the most basic things that are all covered in the official manual. Do you want people to copy and paste the documentation here for you?

Comment: ok tell me where is the answer for this particular answer show me in documentation of cakephp3.0 how to create a skinny controller show me .

Comment: No. Learn how to learn and use a book. Hint: Start reading at page one, from top to bottom, the whole page, one by one in numeric order: http://book.cakephp.org/ If you would have spent 1 minute reading the page you would have notice the word "controller" appears there multiple times. Being able to use documentation is a base skill for a developer. Being able to use documentation will help you in the long run and allow you to make progress without depending on spoon-feeding and trial and error.

Comment: ok thanks for advice as a senior developer you see documents as experienced as a starter to mvc I need some simple help I ask question on stackoverflow in cakephp not only for my solution for others who will face this kind of problem so you can see my questions are basic .

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution how to create skinny controller in cakephp3.0

I have a mysql table called messages and I created a two file one MessagesTable.php here is the code :

```
enter code here  <?php
        // src/Model/Table/UsersTable.php
       namespace App\Model\Table;

      use Cake\ORM\Table;
     use Cake\Validation\Validator;
    use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

      class MessagesTable extends Table
     {



     public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
    $validator
        ->notEmpty('title')
        ->notEmpty('messages');

    return $validator;
    }



     function myMessages() {
      $query = $this->find('all');
      $results = $query->all();
      $data = $results->toArray();

      return $data;



      }



       }
```

Here I created a function called  function myMessages()

And I called it in messagescontroller.php using :

```
   $data = $this->Messages->myMessages();
```

full code is :

```
   $data = $this->Messages->myMessages();

    foreach ($data as $row){
   echo $row->title;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps and change ArticlesTable class and controller class as per your Table and controller name:
Create ArticlesTable.php under src\Model\Table folder as below

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{

}
?>
```

In controller:

```
$data = $this->Articles->find();
foreach ($data as $row){
  echo $row->title;
}
```